# localStorage is not submitting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to use localStorage in JavaScript to save user information (sign-up's, logins and guest users).

At this moment, my complete code is in https://jsfiddle.net/pxbx7zza/

The current problem is not getting the info from the sign-up form (the third one from the left). That works fine, for now. The real problem comes when I try to login the user and validate if that user is in the system and if it has submitted his/her password correctly. That just don't work.

The info submitted in the form goes straight to the link (I'm assuming it's using the "GET" method). To stop this from happening, I have used this piece of code:

```
$("#login").submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

This seemed to work with the sign-up form but not with the login form.

So I have started to see with console.log() how long did the code go but also found that the main function gets executed two times, which is kinda odd when it only does this...

```
function main (){
    var registo = document.getElementById("submeter");    
    var login_id = document.getElementById("login-botao");
    console.log(login_id);

    if(registo != null) {                   
        registo.addEventListener("click", criar_conta);
        $("#registo").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    } else if(login_id != null) {
        login_id.addEventListener("click", login);
        $("#login").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
}
.............................
.............................
.............................
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {main()});
```

Comment: I would be more interested in seeing the question condensed down to the issue it ends up asking about.  Currently it leads in eluding to an issue with localStorage, and ends up asking something completely different.